# Transpose pipe-separated csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a pipe separated csv file that I need to transpose before loading elsewhere. How to I change the row to columns on each pipe "|"?

So the three lines I want to transpose are in csv like below:

```
CountryCode|AFG| ALB| DZA
CountryISO2|AF| AL| DZ
CountryName|Afghanistan| Albania| Algeria
```

and I am after:

```
Country Code|CountryISO2|CountryName
AFG         |AF         |Afghanistan
ALB         |AL         |Albania
DZA         |DZ         |Algeria
```

I've tried using pandas DataFrame and transposing but this takes all the values and loads into a single cell.

```
df_csv = pd.DataFrame(data=csv)
transposed_csv = df_csv.T
print(transposed_csv)
```

ends up like this:

```
                        0                      1
[CountryCode|AFG| ALB|] [CountryISO2|AF| AL|] [CountryName|Afghanistan| Albania]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your problem is that the dataframe is not properly loaded.
You have to read csv with sep='|' and then you can transpose it.

```
df_csv = pd.read_csv(data=file.csv, sep='|')

df_csv.T


0   1
CountryCode CountryISO2 CountryName
AFG AF  Afghanistan
ALB AL  Albania
DZA DZ  Algeria
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a separator

```
import pandas as pd
df_csv = pd.read_csv("PATH_TO_CSV_FILE_HERE", sep='|')
transposed_csv = df_csv.set_index('CountryCode').T
print(transposed_csv)
```

```
CountryCode CountryISO2  CountryName
AFG                  AF  Afghanistan
 ALB                 AL      Albania
 DZA                 DZ      Algeria
```

Answer (score 0):

Full approach (as needed, the expected output is also pipe-separated `|`):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv_data = '''CountryCode|AFG| ALB| DZA
CountryISO2|AF| AL| DZ
CountryName|Afghanistan| Albania| Algeria'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data), sep='\|\s*', header=None, index_col=0)
new_csv = df.T.to_csv(sep='|', index=None)
print(new_csv)
```

The output:

```
CountryCode|CountryISO2|CountryName
AFG|AF|Afghanistan
ALB|AL|Albania
DZA|DZ|Algeria
```